# Can I Set Up an Airflow Docker Container with Python 3.11 using Docker Compose?

Tags: docker-compose, airflow

I have installed Airflow in my WSL Ubuntu environment using your docker-compose.yml for version 2.6.3.

My intention is to schedule and run my Python program with Airflow.

However, my program is using the latest version of the numpy library on Python 3.10. When I inspected the Airflow container, it appears to be using Python 3.7.17.

After extensive research to resolve this, I found that Airflow 2.6.3 supports Python 3.11.

Therefore, I used a Dockerfile to build the container and installed Python 3.10 during the build process. Despite my efforts, the built container remained unchanged on Python 3.7.17, and I have not been able to solve this problem.

While I could modify my program if I fail to resolve this issue, I'd rather gain new knowledge by solving it if possible.
I'm attaching my Dockerfile below. I would appreciate any help you could provide.

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.6.3

USER root

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        build-essential \
        libssl-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libbz2-dev \
        libreadline-dev \
        libsqlite3-dev \
        wget \
        curl \
        llvm \
        libncurses5-dev \
        libncursesw5-dev \
        xz-utils \
        tk-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        liblzma-dev \
        python3-openssl \
        git \
    && curl -L https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.0/Python-3.10.0.tgz -o python.tgz \
    && tar xvf python.tgz \
    && cd Python-3.10.0 \
    && ./configure --enable-optimizations \
    && make altinstall \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


RUN sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/local/bin/python3.10 1
RUN python --version
USER airflow
RUN pip --version

COPY requirements.txt ./
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FROM apache/airflow:2.6.3-python3.11

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

go to setup.py and change this line for the **python_requires** variable
to this:

```
    python_requires=">=3.7,<3.12"
```

Please note that this is not officially supported.

[link to docs file](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/composer-local-dev/blob/main/setup.py)

OR

You can create a docker compose file with 3.11

1. Create a directory for your Airflow project.
2. Create a file called docker-compose.yaml in the directory you just created.
3. Paste the following code into the docker-compose.yaml file:

   version: '3' services: airflow: image: apache/airflow:3.11.0-python3.11 container_name: airflow
4. Save the docker-compose.yaml file.
5. Run the following command to start the Airflow container:

   docker-compose up

The Airflow container will start up and be accessible on port 8080.

You can access the Airflow web UI by opening a web browser and navigating to http://localhost:8080.